# ImageRenderer writes a different image to a PDF file when using LinearGradient

Tags: macos, pdf, swiftui

## Environment

- Xcode 14.3.1
- macOS 13.5.1

## Content

I'm using `ImageRenderer` to write view images to a PDF file by referencing an Apple document:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/imagerenderer#Rendering-to-a-PDF-context

But `ImageRenderer` writes an image to a PDF file that's different from what's rendered in an actual window when using `LinearGradient`.

How do I solve this problem?

The code is as follows:

```swift
let size = CGSize(width: 480, height: 480)

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Save PDF") { renderImage() }
                .buttonStyle(.bordered)
            RenderView()
        }
        .padding()
    }
    
    @MainActor
    func renderImage() {
        let renderer = ImageRenderer(
            content: RenderView()
                .frame(width: size.width, height: size.height)
        )
        renderer.render { size, renderer in
            var mediaBox = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: size)
            guard let consumer = CGDataConsumer(url: URL(filePath: "/****/Hoge.pdf") as CFURL),
                  let pdfContext = CGContext(consumer: consumer, mediaBox: &mediaBox, nil)
            else {
                return
            }
            pdfContext.beginPDFPage(nil)
            pdfContext.translateBy(
                x: mediaBox.size.width / 2 - size.width / 2,
                y: mediaBox.size.height / 2 - size.height / 2
            )
            renderer(pdfContext)
            pdfContext.endPDFPage()
            pdfContext.closePDF()
        }
    }
}

struct RenderView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Text("Hello, World!")
                .font(.largeTitle)
                .foregroundStyle(.white)
            LinearGradient(
                colors: [.clear, .clear, .white],
                startPoint: .top,
                endPoint: .bottom
            )
            .opacity(0.4)
        }
        .frame(width: size.width, height: size.height)
        .background(Color.red)
        .cornerRadius(16)
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

## Screenshots

- A view that's rendered in an actual window

[image: A view that's rendered in an actual window]

- A view that's rendered in a PDF file

[image: A view that's rendered in a PDF file]

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the PDF renderer struggles when it comes to using transparent colors for the gradient.

If you switch the gradient colors to solid colors then it works. So, a foreground color of `.clear` over a background color of `.red` can be replaced by solid red. You can still apply an `.opacity` modifier to the gradient itself, that seems to work without problems:

```swift
LinearGradient(
    colors: [.red, .red, .white],
    startPoint: .top,
    endPoint: .bottom
)
.opacity(0.4)
```

[image: Hoge.pdf]